# Figure grid issue in Foundation 5

Tags: grid, tags, zurb-foundation, figure

Simple Zurb foundation 5 code with image in div class:

```
 `<header class="row">
 <div class="large-4 columns">
 <img alt="Bar chart" src="analytics.gif" />
 <figcaption>Figure Caption Here
 </figcaption>
 </div>

 <hgroup class="large-2 columns">
 <h1>Heading1</h1>
 <h2>Heading2</h2>
 </hgroup>

 <nav class="large-6 small-12 columns">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>`
```

But when div class is replaced by figure:
    `<figure class="large-4 columns">
    <img alt="Bar chart" src="analytics.gif" />
    <figcaption>Figure Caption Here
    </figcaption>
    </figure>`

Now due to figure tag layout breaks, figure tag displaces. Any solution ?

Comment: The link to fiddle or codepen demo would be great.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption without having a live site to look at your code would be that you haven't removed the margins off of the `figure` element added by default by most browsers.

**Default `figure` styling on webkit**

```
figure {
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
   -webkit-margin-end: 40px;
}
```

Foundation by default includes normalize.css which sets `figure` elements to `display:block;`, however it does not remove the default margins applied to it. Try this:

**Potential fix**

```
figure{
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and used:

```
figure{
margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Added the `1em` for **top** and **bottom** **margins** and the removed the `0` from the **left** and **right**.

Otherwise you can go into `Foundation 5` and make modifcations there to the `normalize.css` file:

```
bower_components > foundation > css > normalize.css > line 165
```